# Check whether an instance of a class exists at runtime

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I need to know how to check if an instance of a given class exists at runtime. So I need to make interactions between this instance and other classes. There is no relationship between these classes (composition, aggregation, and inheritance). So how do you get the reference for this class if it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know if (or how many times) a class has been instantiated, just keep a counter in the class:

```
class Foo:
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Foo.counter += 1

Foo()
print(Foo.counter)
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep a handle on all the instances (by reference), instead store `self`:

```
class Foo:
    classes = []

    def __init__(self):
        Foo.classes.append(self)

Foo()
print(Foo.classes[0])
```